# How do you choose a specific card in Java CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, cardlayout

I am using a card layout as a refreshing element on a JFrame and want to switch to a specific card after the user selects a button. Is there a way to call a specific card in the CardLayout on an action event?

```
public class ComboBoxTest() extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        JButton cb = new JButton("next");
        cb.setActionCommand(next);
        cb.addActionListener(this);
        cb.setText("Forward");
        this.add(cb);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);
        
        JButton cb2 = new JButton("next");
        cb2.setActionCommand(previous);
        cb2.addActionListener(this);
        cb2.setText("Back");
        this.add(cb2);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb2);
        
        //Create the "cards".
        card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.add(HomeGui.getBody());
        
        card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(HomeGui.getSecondCard());
        
        card3 = new JPanel();
        card3.add(Start.getbody());
        
        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, next);
        cards.add(card2, previous);
        
        Container base = getContentPane();
        pane.add(header, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        pane.add(cards);
    }
 
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
        String button = e.getActionCommand();
        if(button.equals(next)) {
            c1.last(cards);
        }
        if(button.equals(previous)) {
            c1.first(cards);
        }
        if(button.equals(card3)) {
            //calls the third, specified card
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use show method of the CardLayout object